# Autofac gives unexpected Component.Target.Activator.LimitType when resolving array

Tags: c#, autofac

Can anyone explain why `Component.Target.Activator.LimitType` shows `Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]` instead of the expected `Foo` when I resolve for an array?  Is this a bug in Autofac?  How can I get the expected limit type = `Foo`?

This is a complete program using Autofac 3.5.2 and .Net 4.5:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<ALoggerModule>();
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
            .As<IFoo>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        Debug.WriteLine("Resolving Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]");
        var metafoos = container.Resolve<Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]>();
        foreach (var metalazyfoo in metafoos)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\tResult is: ".PadRight(39) + metalazyfoo.Value.Value.TheALogger.LimitType);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Resolving Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>");
        var secondmetalazyfoo = container.Resolve<Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>>();
        Debug.WriteLine("\tResult is: ".PadRight(39) + secondmetalazyfoo.Value.Value.TheALogger.LimitType);
        Debug.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public static string GetPrettyName(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genargNames = type.GetGenericArguments().Select(GetPrettyName);
            var idx = type.Name.IndexOf('`');
            var typename = (idx > 0) ? type.Name.Substring(0, idx) : type.Name;

            return String.Format("{0}<{1}>", typename, String.Join(", ", genargNames));
        }
        else if (type.IsArray)
        {
            return String.Format("{0}[]", GetPrettyName(type.GetElementType()));
        }

        return type.Name;
    }
}



public interface IFoo
{
    ALogger TheALogger { get; }
}


public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public ALogger TheALogger { get; private set; }

    public Foo(ALogger aLogger) { TheALogger = aLogger; }
}


public class ALogger
{
    public string LimitType { get; private set; }

    public ALogger(string limitType)
    {
        LimitType = limitType;
    }
}

public class ALoggerModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Parameters = args.Parameters.Union(new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    predicate: (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ALogger), 
                    valueAccessor: (p, i) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\tComponent.Activator.LimitType:        {0}", args.Component.Activator.LimitType.GetPrettyName()));
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\tComponent.Target.Activator.LimitType: {0}", args.Component.Target.Activator.LimitType.GetPrettyName()));
                        return new ALogger(args.Component.Target.Activator.LimitType.GetPrettyName());
                    })
            });
        };
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Resolving Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]
    Component.Activator.LimitType:        Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]
    Component.Target.Activator.LimitType: Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]
    Result is:                            Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>[]
Resolving Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>
    Component.Activator.LimitType:        Meta<Lazy<IFoo>>
    Component.Target.Activator.LimitType: Foo
    Result is:                            Foo
Done
```

Comment: This is because [`CollectionRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/c9b56b7737df387afa667a6833b9d6100f6100be/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs).`IsAdapterForIndividualComponents` return false. It is quite difficult to answer the question as is, could you precise why you need to know that ?

Comment: It's related to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086194/iautofacactionfilter-injecting-a-logger).  I'm trying to get the actual service type for the logger.  But both of the `LimitType`s are the same.  So what do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to know who is resolving `ALogger`.

Your code use a custom parameter which is injected while the base type is preparing. Using this, you are able to access the base type.

The problem now is that you want to resolve `IEnumerable<IFoo>` but due to the way [`CollectionRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/c9b56b7737df387afa667a6833b9d6100f6100be/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs) works you are not able to get what you want.

You can try to cast the resolving context to `IInstanceLookup` and obtain what you want :

```
protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
    IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
{
    registration.Preparing += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Preparing {0}", registration.Activator
                                                       .LimitType
                                                       .GetPrettyName());

        args.Parameters = args.Parameters.Union(new[]
        {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                predicate: (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ALogger), 
                valueAccessor: (pi, c) =>
                {
                    Parameter limitTypeParameter = null; 
                    IInstanceLookup lookup = c as IInstanceLookup; 
                    if(lookup != null)
                    {
                        String prettyName = lookup.ComponentRegistration
                                                  .Activator
                                                  .LimitType
                                                  .GetPrettyName();
                        limitTypeParameter = new NamedParameter("limitType", prettyName); 
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        limitTypeParameter = new NamedParameter("limitType", null); 
                    }

                    return c.Resolve<ALogger>(limitTypeParameter); 
                })
        });
    };
}
```